# Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, call-center

I am using ringcentral salesforce integration when i click on (click to dial)  it is not working.

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content 
Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-032a7430-abba-9676-3414- 
bc716a97a74f' 
chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.visualforce.com 
https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/ https://static.cs62.salesforce.com". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce 
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

this is my browser console log

Comment: Have you tried reading this article? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215990/lightingcontainer-refused-to-load-the-script-https-www-youtube-com-iframe You might get solutions from here. Regards.

Comment: Any solution, I am having this error in my CTI :(